# What is the TTL for Datagrams send per DatagramSocket in Java?

Tags: java, android, datagram

How to determine the time-to-live of a Datagram, when its sent from a DatagramSocket and inside Multicast-Adressrange? I try to find out how far the DP is routed, but I cant find anything useful under [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html). MulticastSocket does provide the option and has the default ttl of 1, which makes the DP stay inside the subnet. But how is the scope of a DP from a DatagramSocket determined? How to make sure everyone inside the group gets the DP?

Answer (score 0):

- The way to 'ensure everyone inside the group gets the DP' is obviously to send it from a `MulticastSocket` and set the TTL appropriately, although  describing that as 'ensuring' is inaccurate, as it only controls the TTL and has no effect on packet drops for other reasons.
- `DatagramSocket` sets the TTL to some default imposed by the platform.

Comment: Any suggestions for Android in UDP.  Under TCP its 64 says this:  http://noahdavids.org/self_published/TTL_values.html    I wonder why android is not more specific about it as it could prevent MulticastSocket implementation